# Adjusting lags to data frame for all variables at one time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plm

Let's take data

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package="plm")
head(Produc)
               state year region     pcap     hwy   water    util       pc   gsp    emp unemp
ALABAMA-1970 ALABAMA 1970      6 15032.67 7325.80 1655.68 6051.20 35793.80 28418 1010.5   4.7
ALABAMA-1971 ALABAMA 1971      6 15501.94 7525.94 1721.02 6254.98 37299.91 29375 1021.9   5.2
ALABAMA-1972 ALABAMA 1972      6 15972.41 7765.42 1764.75 6442.23 38670.30 31303 1072.3   4.7
ALABAMA-1973 ALABAMA 1973      6 16406.26 7907.66 1742.41 6756.19 40084.01 33430 1135.5   3.9
ALABAMA-1974 ALABAMA 1974      6 16762.67 8025.52 1734.85 7002.29 42057.31 33749 1169.8   5.5
ALABAMA-1975 ALABAMA 1975      6 17316.26 8158.23 1752.27 7405.76 43971.71 33604 1155.4   7.7
```

I want to add lags for each variable starting from pcap. I know that I can use :

```
  Produc %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(pcap = dplyr::lag(pcap, n = 1, default = NA))
```

But I found it very inefficient because I have to do this for each variable separetly. Is there any possibility how it can be done in one time ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

New_Produc <- Produc %>% mutate(across(.cols = c("pcap","hwy","water","util"), .fns = lag, n = 1, default = NA))
```

If you want to change names:

```
New_Produc <- Produc %>% mutate(across(.cols = c("pcap","hwy","water","util"), .fns = lag, .names = 'lag_{.col}', n = 1, default = NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

we just need to use

```
  View(Produc %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate_at(4:length(Produc), lag))
```

Comment: `mutate_at` is deprecated in recent release of dplyr. Please use something like `mutate(across(pcap:unemp, dplyr::lag, n = 1, default = NA))` instead.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with means package `plm` provides.
First, make your data a pdata.frame so it is panel-aware (so you lag by within each group (state)). Then `lapply` plm's `lag` function over the columns and reconstruct the pdata.frame:

```
pProduc <- pdata.frame(Produc)
l <- lapply(as.list(pProduc[ ,-c(1:3)], keep.attributes = TRUE), lag)
df  <- as.data.frame(l)
df  <- data.frame(Produc[ , 1:3], df) # plug-in index columns again
pdf <- pdata.frame(df)
head(pdf)

               state year region     pcap     hwy   water    util       pc   gsp    emp unemp
ALABAMA-1970 ALABAMA 1970      6       NA      NA      NA      NA       NA    NA     NA    NA
ALABAMA-1971 ALABAMA 1971      6 15032.67 7325.80 1655.68 6051.20 35793.80 28418 1010.5   4.7
ALABAMA-1972 ALABAMA 1972      6 15501.94 7525.94 1721.02 6254.98 37299.91 29375 1021.9   5.2
ALABAMA-1973 ALABAMA 1973      6 15972.41 7765.42 1764.75 6442.23 38670.30 31303 1072.3   4.7
ALABAMA-1974 ALABAMA 1974      6 16406.26 7907.66 1742.41 6756.19 40084.01 33430 1135.5   3.9
ALABAMA-1975 ALABAMA 1975      6 16762.67 8025.52 1734.85 7002.29 42057.31 33749 1169.8   5.5
```